# How do I make a JS function only run once per spam of calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to make a function in jQuery to let a div move up faster than the rest of the page when you scroll down, and have it do the same for the opposite direction.

This **works**, but with a 1.5 second cooldown to avoid the spam from `$(window).scroll(function()`. So people have to wait 1.5 seconds when they join the site for it to work and then they have to wait 1.5 seconds to scroll up and down each time to see the effect work perfectly.

How would I go around fixing this **delay**? There should be **no** delay for good user experience. (The transition function is from a library and is not at fault here.)

```
var $intervalReady = false;
setInterval(function(){if($intervalReady==false){
    $intervalReady = true;
}}, 1500);

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $elementBeginPos = $('#headertext').position();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      var top = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(top > 60 && $intervalReady==true){
        $('#headertext').transition({y:'30%'});
        $intervalReady = false;
      }
      else if(top < 60 && $intervalReady==true){
        $('#headertext').transition({y:'-30%'});
        $intervalReady = false;
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you are not opposed to using a 3rd party library then check out [lodash throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle)

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you for that. You'd think that jQuery or JS would support this, but nope. I'd still like to see if someone has a non-library answer, though.

Comment: Well the non-library answer would be similar to what you're doing but somehow throttle the execution of the funciton at the start of the 1500 ms so you start with `$intervalReady=true` so at the start you execute it instantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/37khp0ft/
Adjust to your needs.

In general, update the state on timer event, not on the scroll event.

JS part:

```
function updatePos(selector, multiplier)
{
   var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop(); 
   $(selector).css({top: scrollPos * multiplier});
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
   setInterval(updatePos, 100,'#div', -1.1 );
});
```

Comment: That really helped, thanks. I think your way is really good and simple. Everyone should use it.